# I cannot import Stream from tweepy

Tags: tweepy

I have tweepy installed, version 4.14.0

However when I try
`from tweepy import Stream`

I obtain the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'Stream' from 'tweepy'`

I think this was working before, has anything changed in the API?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like support for the API v1.1 status/filter endpoint may have been removed.

Changelog here: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/changelog.html#twitter-api-backwards-incompatible-changes